# Anyone know how to make JavaServer Faces h:outputText f:convertNumber display BigDecimal as dollars?

Tags: primefaces, currency

When I have a BigDecimal whose value is 34.31 and I display it with the following code:

```
<h:outputText value="#{invoice.invoiceHeader.totalInvoiceAmt}">
    <f:convertNumber pattern="#0.00" type="currency" currencyCode="USD" currencySymbol="$"/>
</h:outputText>
```

I was expecting it to display $34.31 but instead it displays 34.31.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try to remove `pattern` attribute. Currency can be set just with two decimal places.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @partlov.

When <f:convertNumber/> has a pattern attribute, the type and currency attributes are ignored.  So with the following:

```
<h:outputText value="#{invoice.invoiceHeader.totalInvoiceAmt}">
    <f:convertNumber pattern="#0.00" type="currency" currencyCode="USD" currencySymbol="$"/>
</h:outputText>
```

Only the pattern="#0.00" is used, so 34.4 becomes 34.40.  But with the following:

```
<h:outputText value="#{invoice.invoiceHeader.totalInvoiceAmt}">
    <f:convertNumber type="currency" currencyCode="USD" currencySymbol="$"/>
</h:outputText>
```

All attributes are used resulting in 34.4 becoming $34.40.